# Parallel Lines, One point on each.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

If I have two parallel lines, and I know only 1 point on each, is it possible to calculate their slope or any other information about them?

Thanks

Comment: You can tell that the points are on the lines. But nothing much beyond that because a priori, a single point on a line cannot define a unique line.

Comment: Let $P$ and $Q$ be the two points. Take **any** line $\ell$ through $P$. Then there is a line through $Q$ parallel to $\ell$. It follows that the pair of parallel lines could have **any** slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

A line which passes through a point $(x_i,y_i)$ can be represented as
$$a(x-x_i)+b(y-y_i)+c=0.$$

Hence, 
$$a(x-x_1)+b(y-y_1)+c=0$$
$$a(x-x_2)+b(y-y_2)+c=0$$
are parallel, and each passes distinct point if $(x_1,y_1)\not=(x_2,y_2)$.

However, the slope cannot be determined.